# Conceptually, why are array addresses not modifiable?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I get that when you declare an array, such as:

```
int Numbers[5];
int *intPtr = NULL;
```

You cannot do the following:

```
Numbers++;
Numbers + 1 = intPtr;
Numbers = NULL;
etc
```

What was the motivation for making the base address (and subsequent addresses) of the array constant (or unmodifiable?) Let's say for some strange reason, I wanted to do this:

```
Numbers + 8 = intPtr;
```

Why doesn't the compiler allow access past the allocated number of ints (5 in this case)?

Comment: You have two different questions here, and the second one has nothing to do with the first one. Also, it's implemented like so because it wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: It's kind of like asking if I name my first kid 'Bill', why can't I later take his name away and give it to my second kid, leaving the first one without a name?  Technically possible, but not such a great idea.

Comment: `Numbers` is an array. What is the meaning of incrementing an array ?

Comment: What do you expect `Numbers + 1 = intPtr;` to do? That wouldn't work even if `Numbers` was a pointer.

Comment: -1 Nonsensical question.

Comment: @CareyGregory The **answer** might be "because that doesn't make sense" (indeed that's what the top answer currently says), but I think the question is perfectly clear.

Comment: @TimothyJones - If the answer is because it doesn't make sense, then the question is nonsensical, or may as well be because it won't yield a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numbers is a name...its type is int [5]. What would Number++ mean here? Is it go to the Numbers[1] or it is go beyond Numbers[5]? From that sense, it would not be clear. Likewise, what would Numbers=NULL mean? Would it mean an implicit free of the space allocated for the array Numbers[5]? This is probably not a c language standard kind of reply...but just an intuitive sense.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of

```
int Numbers[5];
```

You aren't defining a pointer. You're defining an array. In reality, the type of `Numbers` is `int[5]`. And that array you're defining, it has a location in memory somewhere. The *base* of that memory is pointed to by `(int *)Numbers`. Since the memory can't be moved anywhere, moving `(int *)Numbers` is also illegal.

And note that this immutability of memory *location* is not confined to arrays. For example:

```
int x;
```

Now, how would you move `x` in memory? If you do `x++`, that increments `x`, but it doesn't move it. And trying to do any math with a pointer to `x` would certainly not move `x` in memory. The location in memory of `x` (or `Numbers`) is set when `x` is created and you can't move it no matter how hard you try. And that goes for any type – you can't move a single integer, and you can't move an array.

Comment: `(&x)` is not an lvalue, you can't increment it, `(&x)++` shouldn't compile, it's analagous to doing `5++`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - thanks. That should've been obvious; I just wasn't thinking. I fixed it.

Comment: "And note that this immutability of memory location is not confined to arrays." However, non-assignability is unique to array types.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will not allow you to do this. Cos, if you do so, you will lose all the 5 elements of the array. 
Also **Numbers** is a variable. You cant change the address of the variable. You can change the value in it.

Answer (score 1):

First we talk about what standard says:6.3.2.1/3 "Other operands/Lvalues, arrays,and function designators":

`Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.`

*Now Why unmodifiable?*

Because as mentioned it is pointer to the initial element of array so any change on this pointer will lead to loss of original array.We can do increment and decrement on copy of this address to access elements of this array.

*Last question:*

What are you trying to find at out of the bound of array.You have requested for 5 elements so got space for [0] to [4]. Accessing [5] is not safe because it is not reserved for you so may lead for segmentation fault, or corrupted data.

Comment: "Because as mentioned it is pointer to the initial element of array" No it is not. An array expression is an array expression. It can get *converted* into a pointer expression in *certain contexts*.

Comment: @newacct agreed but i just talked about array name which is pointer to its first element.Making an increment on array name is that _certain context_ for which you are talking about.Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the value of `Numbers` because `Numbers` is not an lvalue. If you try something like `Numbers++`, the compiler will complain that you're trying to assign to something that's not an lvalue.

The reason that `Numbers` isn't an lvalue is that it's the name of an array. If you change the value of `Numbers`, you'll have no way to refer to the array, which makes the array pointless. You can, however, make a copy of the value of `Numbers` and modify that, like:

```
int numbers[5];
int *n = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
printf("numbers is: %p\n", n);
n++;                            // this is OK
printf("numbers is: %p\n", n);
```

Notice that `n` is a pointer, while `numbers` is not a pointer but an array.

Comment: "The reason that Numbers isn't an lvalue is that it's the name of an array." I don't think this explains anything. C could have made it an lvalue so that if you assigned another `int[5]` array to it, it copied all the elements over into this array, and the location of the array does not change. (In fact this is what happens when an array is a member of a struct and you assign the struct.) The fact that that's not supported is a language design choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do something like this:

```
Numbers + 8 = intPtr;
```

with any variable, never mind an array. Perhaps you mean something like this, which is legal for both pointers and arrays:

```
int main(void) {
    int array[5];
    int * p;

    p = array;

    *(p + 3) = 4;        /* works */
    *(array + 4) = 5;    /* also works */

    return 0;
}
```

Why you'd want to try assigning the value of an `int *` to the 9th element of of a 5-element array of `int` is beyond me, however.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot do that is becuase this could potentially corrupt the (process) memory. So, if we allocate "int Numbers[5]", then this reserves a contiguous memory of 5 integers. When you go beyond this region of 5 integers, then you are accessing a memory region which is not assigned to the array -- it is possible that this region is being used by some other variable.

If you need additional space in your array, then you can use either dynamic arrays or linked list. With dynamic arrays, you create a new array, copy all the elements to the new storage, and free the old array. With linked lists, we malloc a new memory region for every node in the list. Then, using the next (or prev) pointers, we make it point to the memory location of the other nodes in the list. But, in both cases, we do not go beyond the memory that is allocated to us.